# Encapsulate the decision which child class to initialize

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a parent class and different child classes. I want to encapsulate the decision which child class is to initialize in the initialization. 
A simple example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        if self.name_is_male(name):
            real_instance = Male(name)
        else:
            real_instance = Female(name)
        return real_instance

    def name_is_male(self, name):
        if name == 'Donald':
            return True
        elif name == 'Daisy':
            return False
        else:
            raise ValueError('unknown name!')

class Male(Person):
    def __init__(self, name):
        ...

class Female(Person):
    def __init__(self, name):
        ...
```

This simple example will end in a recursion and doesn’t work, but it’s for illustrating my question: how to encapsulate the decision which child class to initialize in the initialization of a parent class? Or is this altogether a stupid idea?

Comment: You can have a `Person` class with `gender` attribute being `'male'` or `'female'`

Comment: Why would you instantiate one class if you need the other ? You can define `name_is_male` as a static method if you want to test the name before creating an instance. (good luck with [those](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unisex_name))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the use case is not very clear, I would have used factory design pattern to achieve something similar to this. A basic example can be:

```
class Person(object):
    # Create objects based on some name:

    @staticmethod
    def factory(name):
        if name== "Male": 
            return Male()
        elif name== "Female": 
            return Female()
        else:
            return None

class Male(Person):
    pass

class Female(Person):
    pass


person = Person.factory('Male')
```

Another example on [factory method design pattern](https://gist.github.com/pazdera/1099559)

Comment: that's exactly what i wanted. i wasn't familiar with this concept. another good explanation: http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html

Comment: This can also be done with `__new__` but a factory function is easier.

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` is not supposed to return anything (or rather: it has to return `None`). Imo it's not the best way of writing it, or as you put it "altogether a stupid idea". Is there a particular reason why it can't be an attribute?